# Quickly place a window to another screen using only the keyboard

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I know that using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, I can use the keyboard to move the window around. I can also use the "Grid" plugin of Compiz to position quickly the window around my current monitor. The grid plugin doesn't seem work across monitor however.

What I need is a quicker way to move the current window to the other screen. In my current dual-monitor setup, I find myself needing to move the focus window to the other monitor as I focus on working on something else (and move it back afterward).

If I use XMonad (or other tiling managers), this would be rather easy. However, many applications that I use (Gnome Do, MATLAB, image viewers, custom apps that I write, ...) do not work well with a tiling manager.

So my question is: is there a shortcut key combination that moves the currently focused window to the other monitor (and back)?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the Alt-F7 shortcut. First time I find the answer I was looking for, in a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move window to monitor on the left/right shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033018/move-window-to-monitor-on-the-left-right-shortcut)

Comment: I'm using Alt-F7. However for a speedup moving with arrows and ctrl. Much faster thought.

Comment: Why not just drag it there with your mouse

Answer (score 207, accepted):

1. Install [CompizConfig Settings Manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Run CCSM → Go to bottom (Window Management) → Go to "Put."
3. Enable the plugin.
4. Configure shortcut for "Put to next Output."
5. Log out and back in again.

If the plugin *put* doesn't appear in CCSM, install the [compiz-plugins [image: Install compiz-plugins]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins) package. (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins`)

EDIT: The required plugin package is now called `compiz-plugins` on 12.10 and higher. [compiz-plugins-extra [image: Install compiz-plugins-extra]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins-extra) is still used for 12.04.

Comment: It's also worth noting that "next" output will cycle through all of the monitors (not stopping on the furthest right).

Comment: I don't see the plug-in. Using Ubuntu QQ

Comment: This didn't work for me, maybe because I'm using nvidia drivers?

Comment: Tried to set up "Put to adjacent viewport" — no luck.

Comment: I enabled the Put extension but it's not working for me -- unlike the regular Compiz Grid commands. Ubuntu 14.04, Dell E7240, Apple Cinema Display.

Comment: Doesn't work for me Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.16, nVidia drivers.

Comment: Ah it does work - just needs a logoff/logon!

Comment: There isn't any option "Put"

Comment: @Richard, you'll have to install `compiz-plugins` as mentioned in the post. (Sidenote: I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 and once that was installed I was the "Put" plugin.)

Comment: I like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Page_Down</kbd> for "put to next output" and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Page_Up</kbd> for "put to previous output".
I prefer to leave the Super key for System-wide commands only.

Comment: it seems this plugin conflicts with the grid one. When a window is placed in one of the grid positions it refuses to be moved to the other screen - it goes there and them comes back. any solution for this?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.10 there is no "Put" option available, can you please provide workaround?

Comment: So what's the preferred shortcuts for `Put to next/prev Output`?

Comment: I couldn't see Put option on Ubuntu 16.04 until i did `sudo apt install compiz-plugins-extra`

Comment: Continues to work in Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Unity 7.5 also. :)

Answer (score 32):

I like **Put to next Output** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>

enjoy it!

[image: Put at CCSM]
Put at CCSM.

[image: Put to Next Output]
Put to Next Output

Comment: Now, I use setting this hotkey to '<Alt><Shift>m'. :P

Comment: I don't have Put in my CCSM

Comment: @JamieHutber you need to install the `compiz-plugins` and then you see it there.

Comment: Thank you Pandian.

Comment: And you need to logoff and log on

Answer (score 24):

On my machine (CentOS Linux 7) it worked out of the box:
Use <kbd>window key</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd> this will move window quickly between monitors
Works on maximized as well as non maximized windows.

Comment: If possible can you please clarify how to achieve this in Ubuntu since this is what question in about.

Comment: Thanks! I have two **monitors** (not talking about workspaces) and it worked fine! [ubuntu budgie 19.04]

Comment: This also works fine for me out of the box on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I can confirm this works in 20.04 LTS as well. Should be the accepted answer, since it does not require any additional installation - just know the keys that were asked for.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + NumLeft/NumRight

for **minimised** window only (!) I found today in Gnome 3 @ Ubuntu 14.04.

i.e., if you wan to move maximized window, you may

'Win + DownArrow', '<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ NumLeft/NumRight', 'Win + UpArrow'

or try to bind it..

Comment: Unfortunately, this `Alt+Ctrl+<NumDirection>` shortcuts keep the window on the same screen and doesn't move to another screen.. tested on Ubuntu 15.04 (w/Unity).

Comment: It's the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04. I came here to find a solution to _this_ problem.

Comment: @Anonsage But  it is for Gnome. Not Unity.

Answer (score 5):

After installing compizconfig-settings-manager → Run it → Go to bottom (Window Management) → Go to "Put."

Then you should try "Put within viewport" and "Put Left/Put Right". If the window is not on the edge of the screen needs double "right/left" to switch over screens. By default is with super+Numpad-Arrows.

Comment: Not the most direct solution, but a better one in my opinion.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: Put is missing. how do I get it? (ubuntu 20 fresh install with unity 7.5)

Answer (score 3):

After install CCSM, to add "put" option, you must install too :

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Addendum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard/868653#answer-22260)**: If the solution with `Put plugin` doesn't work.

Try to disable some features you don't use that may interfere. I left only `Put To Next Output` enabled and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the features in "Grid" plugin on ccsm, logoff/logon, and enable the "put" plugin with combination keys that you want. Works for me (ubuntu 16.04).

I enable some features in both plugin because I wanted move windows between monitors (using features on put), but I wanted keep the feature that resize the window by half of width of the current monitor (using features on grid).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the top of the window on the bar and a drop down appeared for me with the option of moving the window.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> on an active window then select *"Move to Monitor Right"*