# Is there a Unity / Compiz shortcut key to move a window to your other monitor (not workspace)?

Tags: 11.04, unity, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quickly place a window to another screen using only the keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard)

Sort of like CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+Arrow but only to my other monitor, not to a completely separate workspace.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard

Answer (score 6):

depending on your monitor setup you can try the (awesome) shortcuts ctrl+alt+numX, where numX is a number on the numpad.

great for quickly resizing a window and/or moving it on the screen.

e.g. ctrl+alt+num4 puts the window on the left side of the screen, ctrl+alt+num6 puts it on the right

Comment: I don't think this works for multiple monitors

Comment: This does work with multiple monitors, but it's monitor sensitive, so if the window is on my left monitor and I press CTRL+ALT+NUM9, it will get moved to the top-right corner of my left monitor. But I'd like something that will move it to the right monitor, at which point I could CTRL+ALT+NUM9 to put it in the top-right corner of my right monitor.