# Can I configure a keyboard shortcut to switch the content when using dual monitors?

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I'm using Ubuntu with two monitors, is there any way to set up a keyboard shortcut that would switch the contents of both monitors? (i.e. move every window from the first monitor to the second and every window from the second to the first).

Answer (score 0):

You can [move a single window from one monitor to another using the keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard). But I don't know a way to swap all windows. Maybe a little scripting based on the Put compiz plugin that allows the keyboard shortcut.