# Keyboard shortcut to move windows between monitors?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window-manager, window

I remember there used to be a setting under Compiz that set a keyboard shortcut for moving applications between physical (but combined as a single xscreen) screens, similar to moving between logical screens, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Any way to do this under Unity?

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard

Comment: That is the Compiz setting I used to use. Was hoping that there was a way to do it under pure unity.

Comment: All Unity is is a huge, big compiz plugin.

Comment: After playing around with keybinds for a while, I've been liking Super+X as a next-monitor keybind.  (on a 2-monitor setup, that always just flips to the other monitor.)  I can quickly hit it with one hand. (super = windows-key.)  super+z might be even easier to hit, but it doesn't have the "x for exchange" mnemonic going for it.

Comment: I can't find this option in the Put plugin on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

As @jrg mentioned, this is still possible as Unity (Unity 3D, not the low-power 2D version) is largely built using Compiz.

You'll need to install the Compiz Config Settings Manager Yourself though. Precise steps are:-

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager using `apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra`.
2. Run it (just type Compiz in the dash and you'll see it).
3. Click `Window Management`.
4. Enable the `Put` plug-in (select the check-box).
5. Click on `Put`.
6. Configure the shortcut for `Put to next Output` (click the pencil icon next to the keyboard shortcut for `Put to next Output`.
7. Logout and login again for the changes to take effect (from the comments!)

Comment: requires a logoff, but yes, this works great!

Comment: Could anyone elaborate on point 4? I've enabled "Put" successfully, but I don't understand how/where to set a shortcut for it?

Comment: When you select 'Put' the window changes and shows 3 more Tabs with settings for Put. On the Bindings tab you can then set key bindings.

Comment: @user50849 You have got to click on 'Put'

Comment: One problem (bug) with this.  If you use "grid" to move (snap) a window into a corner of one screen for example, for whatever reason, when you try to move it to the other screen, it will move for a second, then bounce back to where it came from.  If this window was unconstrained (not snapped to any grid boundary) then it moves fine.  But if constrained at all it won't move properly.  Somewhat annoying. :-/

Comment: If you really don't want to log-off, you can hit `Alt-F2` and execute `compiz --replace`

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04. Not working. I press the hotkey I assigned and nothing happens.

Comment: How do you set the shortcut (e.g., super+alt+right-arrow)?

Comment: This does work in 16.06 for me. Don't forget to logout and back in.

Comment: I did and it works as soon as I configured. Logout was not necessary! Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I don't see where the settings for step 6 are. Are you still talking about something inside Compiz?

Comment: Weird bug in 18.04: enabling "Put" seems to disable the Launcher shortcuts (e.g. terminal, home folder, etc.)

Comment: @joniba click on the Disabled (or key input) button and select "Grab key combination" then press the key combo you want to use.  Although for two monitors something like "Ctrl + Alt" would suffice as it will switch between the two monitors.

Comment: well I would avoid using "Ctrl + Alt" actually since "Ctrl + Alt + T" is used to open a terminal for example and it would do both actions with that command..

Answer (score 40):

This is based on my experience without the need for Compiz or any such utility.

When a window is activated (i.e. in-focus) If you press `Alt + Space` the top menu appears which has options like:

```
Minimize
Maximize
Move
Resize
etc.
```

Once that menu appears you need to press `M` key on your keyboard to select the `Move` option

Then you can just use the arrow keys to move the windows anywhere (even across monitors)

Comment: awesome, in Ubuntu 16.01 there is also a `Move to monitor left` option

Comment: I want to see this option, but I haven't seen it in 16.04 or 18.04, I'm somewhat annoyed by the compiz solution.

Answer (score 15):

Move window from left monitor to right monitor:
<kbd>Super</kbd> (i.e. Windows key)+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd>

Move window from right monitor to left monitor:
<kbd>Super</kbd>(i.e. Windows key)+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>

Comment: I found this just worked out the box for me on 18.4

Comment: Any idea why this does not work in 20.4?

Comment: Doesn't work. No option like that even exists in the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: works out of the box in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 13):

Compiz Config Settings Manager's *Put* plug-in works great on **13.04** and **14.04**

Special hint:

- Click on Put -> Misc. Options -> Activate "Avoid Offscreen": Avoids putting parts of the moved window to a hidden area. Very useful if someone has got monitors with different display resolutions.

Comment: If you want to do this you can just press alt+f7, at least in 16.04

Answer (score 6):

Compiz `put` works great, just be carefull if `grid` is active (it usually is) **you'll find a compatibility bug** those windows that are already grit to some corner of your workspace will bounce back if you try to `put` them to another output.

If this happens to you don't panic, just do the following:

Before you send your window to the next output, `"ungrid" it` by semi-maximizing it to one side <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>lef or right</kbd> and bam!, now you can send it and it wont spring back.

It **works on both** `12.04` and `14.04`

( Now, who knows... maybe this is one of those cases where the responsible developer will protest "it's a feature not a bug!" xD )

Comment: This bug is really annoying and I use the same workaround but when developing it really drives me crazy as my IDE windows sometimes change monitors without warning because I've set them to another monitor, and clicked to minimize them without thinking about it

Comment: It is definitely super annoying, if I was a better C programmer I'd contribute to remove the bug, maybe another time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to move windows (in case of windows that do not appear "anywhere") and excluding Compiz or other managers, the simple way I've used is this:

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> (should open the windows menu, even if it's also
  not seen)
- (pressing <kbd>M</kbd> [for Move] does not work for me in Ubuntu 19.04)
- press <kbd>↓</kbd> twice (skipping the first 2 options: Minimize and Maximize/Unmaximize) + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- press directional arrows until you see its top-bar on any monitor, and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- you should now be able to control it normally...