# Program/Keyboard shortcut to work with multiple monitors

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, alternative

So I have a desktop with one DVI monitor and DP to HDMI monitor. My question is is there any keyboard shortcut or programs for multiple monitors? My example is Windows 7/8 and DisplayFusion. In Windows 7/8 When you press Start with left/right, it will cycle through all the monitors. In 14.04, Ctrl+Super with left/right, in only does it for one monitor. It doesnt go to the other monitor, so I have to drag it to the other monitor first before snapping it to left/right side. In Windows using DisplayFusion, pressing certain keboard shortcut will transfer one 'window' to another monitor. In Ubuntu, I did not found any.

In a way, Windows 7/8 plus DisplayFusion makes working multiple monitors really easy using keyboard shortcut. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I have not able to find anything that can match my example in Ubuntu or Linux. Almost all of the pages I go through using Google shows me how to setup multiple monitors.

So I was wondering, with the release of 14.04, is there anything that I should know about working with switching/snapping/transferring 'window/program' with multiple monitors. I know keyboard binding might work, but I absolutely have no idea what to bind to. Maybe there is program somewhere out there that I didn't manage to find. Maybe a script in transferring window from one monitor to another monitor. Its nice to see when you use multiple workspace, you can easily transfer application to other workspace, but multiple monitors, not so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut to move windows between monitors?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141752/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-windows-between-monitors)