# Keyboard shortcut to move windows between multiple workspaces in 18.04

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I've always loved multiple workspaces, and I used up to 8 in my beloved 14.04.
Now in 18.04 I understand we are in GNOME and not Unity, and there isn't a way to tweak much the workspace thing.

I can live with the Super button, and the vertical, dynamic workspace system, but I can't find a way to *move* windows from one workspace to the next using the keyboard.

I combed this site and found several answers, but they seem outdated and don't solve the problem for the 18.04.

I also installed `compizconfig-settings-manager` (as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141752/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-windows-between-monitors)), but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there a GNOME extension I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the **Settings** application and go to *Devices* > *Keyboard*.

You would be able to find the preset shortcuts to move a window between workspaces here and also change these to ones you prefer. Even if no shortcuts are assigned, you can set new ones.