# Howto to move window to another monitor on the left/right using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I have always used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to move windows from left to right monitors.

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 last week (fresh install) and it appears that this is not working anymore despite the fact I had configured them like this in the Keyboard settings.

I'm guessing these shortcuts are already in use somewhere, but I have no clue where...
They are **not** listed in the Keyboard settings though and it does not indicate any kind of conflict.

Anyone knows how I can get this the way I want it ?

---

Edit:
So to be perfectly clear. I've set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> > keyboard...
But when hitting the shortcut keys, nothing happens.

Comment: I cleaned all bindings, to find them use `dconf dump / | grep left`, but Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right still aren't forwarded to apps.

Comment: also check for <Primary> as key instead of <Ctrl>... also saw <Control> I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@hiigaran's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033018/howto-to-move-window-to-another-monitor-on-the-left-right-using-keyboard-shortcu/1033057#comment1680097_1033019)

> I see. So the problem is that the gnome-control-center is not honoring your changes to the default hotkeys. What is returned when you do "dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-monitor-left"?

I checked out `dconf`. It appears my shortcut keys were, as I supposed, in use already for move window to **workspace** left/right

These settings do not appear in the keyboard settings though as there are no lateral workspaces anymore !!
I guess it is a bug that these actions, although no longer available, still have an assigned shortcut key.

I simply removed the set shortcut keys and everything it working again.

Answer (score 157):

In Ubuntu >= 18.04, the default hotkeys for moving windows to another monitor are <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>. Each arrow will correspond to the location of the destination monitor relative to where the focused window is.

Also, are you saying that you do not see a list of hotkeys in *Settings > Devices > Keyboard*?
I assume you are using `gnome-control-center`.

Comment: I know about the default... BUT have been using Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Arrow for over 10 years and seems legitimate to be able to change these settings. 
Everything is fine in Settings > Devices > Keyboard... I've got my settings there... But the set shortcuts don't work

Comment: I see. So the problem is that gnome-control-center is not honouring your changes to the default hotkeys. What is returned when you do "dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-monitor-left"?

Comment: Cheers... This pointed me on the right direction.

Comment: ok the program moved, but the mouse cursor doesn't move with it. Still, it is taking the same effort like moving your program with the cursor. how to move the app along with cursor if anything like this is possible.

Comment: thank you ! thats the second time i find this answer useful. i'd like to upvote it twice :D

Answer (score 16):

What also works is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to grab the window and then move it with the Arrow-keys and release it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Alt-Tab also helps by allowing you to select a window from a ribbon the window you want to move.

Answer (score 2):

Move a window between monitors => `supers + shift + ctrl + arrow up/down`

Move a window between workspaces => `supers + shift + arrow up/down`

Move between workspaces => `supers + ctrl + arrow up/down`

Put a window at left/right half of screen => `supers + ctrl + arrow left/right`

Answer (score 1):

In unity: go to settings -> shortcuts -> windows and then change "Move window" accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

In *almost all* window managers, not necessarily Ubuntu-specific, but works (On Linux, as well as Windows! Even as early as Windows 95!)

Alt-Space M to move window using the arrow keys. Press and hold down Shift while using the arrow keys to move window *rapidly* (to the other monitor or far side of the screen). Or nudge the mouse with a stick (filthy mice, don't want to touch them).

Press Enter to finalize the move.