# Quickly place a window to another screen using only the keyboard (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager

I followed [Quickly place a window to another screen using only the keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard) to be able to shift my windows through different screens but nothing seems to happen. Is there anything else necessary to make this work in Xubuntu?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48456/xfce-send-window-to-other-monitor-on-keystroke[enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48456/xfce-send-window-to-other-monitor-on-keystroke) try this